# How to start up my computer (wake on LAN) from command line?

Tags: ssh, wake-on-lan

I would like to SSH to my home computer (Mac Snow Leopard) but I don't always know if it's on. I have enabled wake on LAN. Is there a way to wake my computer (or check if it's awake) from the command line?

Answer (score 5):

You'd have to have a second, awake computer (or WoL-capable router) on the LAN to send the magic packet. It is [Wake-on-LAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN), after all.

The router method is easier. Check out this [DD-WRT article](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/WOL) to get it going.